# How to convert speech to text in python input from audio file

Tags: python, speech-to-text

speech to text in python using audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer for this question.
You have install pyaudio and SpeechRecognition.
and audio file format should be in **WAV file**.

**Its code for speech to text (input from audio file).**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

audio = 'trial.wav'

with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    print ('Done!')

try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print (text)

except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: trial.wav file is audio file name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want different languages to be converted. You can use below code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile('Audio.wav') as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = (r.recognize_google(audio, language="IN_HI"))
        print('working on...')
        print(text)
    except:
        print('Sorry.. run again..')
```

Comment: If you are unsure about your language code. Below is the link where you can find it all https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages

Comment: To my dismay, can't find Scottish English on any cloud platform (Azure, AWS, Google). Any idea why please?